# How to get all permutations of items in matrix excluding rotation clones

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I made a python program which solves a logical puzzle game that I bought for my kid. The program already works but gives 4 solutions instead of 1 and works 4 times slower than it should. It happens because currently it uses permutations (from itertools) to generate all possible ordering of puzzle elements but it can be optimized. Let me try to explain:

I have a list of nine unique elements [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I] that represents a matrix 3x3:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

I need to generate all possible permutations of that list but exclude clones that comes from rotating the matrix so for above list the clones are:

```
[C,F,I,B,E,H,A,D,G]
[I,H,G,F,E,D,C,B,A]
[G,D,A,H,E,B,I,F,C]
```

because they represents matrixes which comes from rotating the first matrix

```
C F I
B E H
A D G

I H G
F E D
C B A

G D A
H E B
I F C
```

Is there some python module that can be used to generate such possibilites? Or maybe you have an idea how such generator may be implemented?

Comment: you should probably set this matrix up as a real matrix in `numpy`, it does calculations faster, including rotation ones (which will allow you to exclude)

Comment: Generate them the same way, but then you can simply discard the permutation where top-left is not the 'smallest' of the corners.

Comment: @Jeffrey this is brilliant idea, simple and powerful, I wish i could figure it out myself :) thanks!